# How to clear partitioned disk for QEMU

Tags: partition, qemu, disk

I have a 100Gb partition for QEMU purposes. However, I was installing Windows 10, but the installation failed and corrupted. Is there a way to completely wipe that partition so I can start over?

Answer (score 0):

```
# lsblk -il | grep part
sda1                                        8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot
sda2                                        8:2    0    40G  0 part  
sda3                                        8:3    0    40G  0 part  
sda4                                        8:4    0  38.8G  0 part
```

If you partition would be 'sda4' then:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda4 bs=1M count=10
```

would be enough.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm getting -bash: sda<number>: command not found